# How to exclude rows by identifying values from two columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data-frames:

df1:

```
 X1  X2   X3
  1   2  100
  2   3   90
  1   3  100
  3   1  110
  2   1   20
  1   3   30
  2   3   40
  3   1   50
```

df2:

```
 X1  X2   X3  Y
  1   2  100  1
  2   3   90  1
  1   3  100  1
  3   1  110  0
  2   1   20  0
  1   3   30  0
  2   3   40  1
  3   1   50  0
```

I want to exclude rows from df1, for those who have the value 1 in Y column in df2.
The identifier is (X1, X2).

Expected result:

```
 X1  X2   X3
  3   1  110
  2   1   20
  3   1   50
```

Comment: you can get the index from df2, ```df2[df2['Y'] == 1].index``` and use that in df1

Comment: why `1   3   30  0` is missing?

Comment: @jezrael Because `(1, 3)` got the value 1 in another row.

Comment: there are same index values in both DataFrames? Or not? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jezrael Different indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` by filtering by `Y` column and remove duplicates for avoid duplicated rows in output:

```
df3 = df2.loc[df2['Y'].eq(1), ['X1','X2']].drop_duplicates()
print (df3)
   X1  X2
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   1   3
```

Then use left join with `indicator=True` parameter in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and filter `left_only` rows:

```
df = df1.merge(df3, indicator=True, how='left').query('_merge =="left_only"').drop('_merge',1)
print (df)
   X1  X2   X3
3   3   1  110
4   2   1   20
7   3   1   50
```